# Jquery how to separate selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such code

`$('select[name$="[country_id]"], select[name$="[region_id]"], select[name$="[city_id]"]').select2();`

I try to rewrite it to

`$('select').find('[name$="[country_id]"], [name$="[region_id]"], [name$="[city_id]"]').select2();`

but not works. Is any solution?

Comment: Which element or elements are you trying to select, `<select>`?

Comment: yes elements <select>

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.filter()`; `.find()` selects child elements of selector

```js
console.log(
  $('select')
  .filter('[name$="[country_id]"], [name$="[region_id]"], [name$="[city_id]"]'))
//  .select2();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="name_[country_id]">
  </select>
<select name="name_[region_id]">
  </select>
<select name="name_[city_id]">
  </select>
<select name="name_[not_city_id]">
  </select>
<select name="name_[not_region_id]">
  </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first expression seems to be correct while the expression with [**find**](https://api.jquery.com/find/)
is changing context.

jquery `find` accepts a string or an element.

While the first expression is a multiple selector while the second  expression is searching value inside *quotes* `[name$="[country_id]"], [name$="[region_id]"], [name$="[city_id]"]` as single string.

So it does not works